# How to categorize retag requests?

Tags: discussion, tags

**Assuming it should be (at least) one or the other**, is a retag request (ie: the recent "Please change 'db-design' to 'database-design'" question) more of a 'discussion' question or a 'feature-request'?

Answer (score 3):

I think a retagging is a discussion. There is no feature as I see it, but it is a decision that merits some validation before being performed to ensure it's the right decision.

Answer (score 3):

Keep them individual, but tag them 'retag-request'. Each one needs its own discussion and voting. They have nothing to do with 'feature-request's though.

Comment: Definitely tag them 'retag-request'.  But pretend for a minute they should also be one or the other of tags from the question.  I take it this means you think 'discussion'?

Comment: @Joel: I would say yes to discussion if I had to choose.

Comment: You **do** have to choose, because `[retag-request]` isn't one of the required tags.

Answer (score 2):

As a "do-er" of these, **personally** I find it easier to have separate questions marked <kbd>retag-request</kbd> and (to satisfy the mandated tags) <kbd>discussion</kbd>. This allows separate tracking (IMO, a good thing), and allows me to [monitor the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag-request). It also invites the **very necessary** input (i.e. discussion) from other users, without it being buried on page 3 of an über-question.

With a [single question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg) it is really tricky; I have to keep scanning through pages of replies (which is trickier than pages of questions, since the questions page is optimized for this, and displays status etc).

Answer (score 1):

I would not classify a retagging request as a feature request since the features of the site are not changing.  I think that using the retagging or retag in the tags area should be sufficient.

Comment: `[retag-request]` isn't one of the required tags, so you would still need to add one of them. Currently most of them are also tagged discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I would request that we put all these retagging requests into a single large question devoted towards the discussion of these requests. It can be a little bit of a pain to see these little Q's constantly hitting the new question screen every time someone wants to change a tag.

Comment: Since it already has some where they've been marked done or not, I'd recommend this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg

Comment: That's exactly what I am talking about. That way people can actually monitor the same thread and see the progress. It would also help reduce the number of times we may see the same requests.

Comment: As opposed to *the same* question constantly hitting the "new question" screen, with no easy way of determining what's been added?

Comment: Shog9: The same question never hits the New Question page more than once.

Comment: @Shoggy: Why would it hit the new question screen?

Comment: Ah, sorry - front page, i mean. Same problem: no easy way to know what's been changed.

Comment: This is a bad idea. This is against how SO.com works. Issue each request as a new question so the system works with us.

Comment: Some of these requests need more discussion than can comfortably fit in comments to one answer.  A common 'retag-request' tag should be good enough to group the various requests together.

Comment: @Joel: I look forward to your green check mark :D

Comment: The point was brought up in the Great Tagging Reorg post that they should be brought up as individual questions, but I'm flexible either way, as long as it's consistent.

Comment: HEY GUYS!  COMPROMISE SOLUTION: retag-requests.stackoverflow.com!  IT'S GENIOUS!

Comment: Pesto -- only if it's localized into Japanese, German, and French

Comment: Personally, I find it **really** hard to manage requests in a single question. If that is the agreed opinion, though, I guess I'll suffer it...

Answer (score 0):

I think that by asking questions, and tagging them with `[retag-request]`, it gives us a better platform for discussing the changes to be made.

If someone has a problem with how these decisions were made, we can direct them to the relevant question. Were they can see the whole discussion easily, and they can leave a comment, or "answer".

In these questions, the community gets to vote, up and down, any action to be taken. This will also make it so that the action that has the most community support, will be at the top.

Comment: By the way there is currently 40 questions tagged `[retag-request]`.